# Saving changes temporarily until published

Tags: database-design

I'm redesigning an existing system and the new specs requires a publish function.
An admin can make changes in a virtual file system, but the changes should not visible to the user before the admin press on the publish button.

I've come up with a few solutions, but they all have a lot of drawbacks.

Here is a stripped down version of the existing design. A node can be a folder or file (linked to the files table). Groups gives the user permission to a node.

[image: stripped down version of the existing design]

Any thoughts on how a design could look like allowing an admin to create/change nodes and groups (permissions) temporarily until a publish function is called?

Comment: Sort of [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598418/what-is-the-best-way-yo-keep-version-on-database) with no concrete answer.

Comment: Another [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947065/database-model-for-live-and-draft-data/947656#947656) with answers to think about, but no winners.